# django template page output No module named blog

Tags: python, django

Im starting with django but this get me one error and i cant run /blog/templates/index.html

ps:
i tried with

```
url(r'^$', 'FirstBlog.blog.views.home', name='home')
```

or

```
url(r'^$', include('views.home'))
```

but this dont work

i also tried

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
)
```

but....

can u help me?

full project: http://www.megafileupload.com/Uih/FirstBlog.tar.gz

django version: 1.7.7

Comment: No one in their right mind would download and unzip a random archive posted by a stranger. Hopefully you have `DEBUG = True` in your settings, so carefully read the error messages that are generated, both in the web browser when you try to access the resource, and in the terminal window where you ran `python manage.py runserver`. They will tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Show your view code for home

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you set TEMPLATES_DIRS in settings.py, it needs to be an absolute path.

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), )
```

Next if your templates folder is within your app, all you need is the string 'index.html',

```
# Function Based View
from django.shortcuts import render


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')  # Render syntax requires (request, template)

# Class based view
from django.views import generic

class Home(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
```

For class based views urls:

```
from blog.views import Home

urlpatterns = [ 
                        url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home'),
                     ]
```

For functions based views urls:

```
url(r'^$', 'blog.views.home', name='home')
```